# onCancelled(Object object) or onCancelled() not being called after i cancel an AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a program that loads up to 100% in the background using AsyncTask and has the feature to cancel whenever I want to, so when I press the 'cancel' button I call this function:

```
protected class CancelButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        _initTask.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

So by documentation it should call the OnCancelled() function in the AsyncTask class but it doesn't as I can figure out from the log. Again I read somewhere that onCancelled() was not being used after Android 4.0, instead we use isCancelled() on onPostExecute() but again from my logs I get that none of these functions are being called neither onPostExecute() nor OnCancelled().
So what is the best way to handle CANCEL code for an AsyncTask, in other words which necessary functions do I have to ovveride.

My MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

protected TextView _percentField;

protected Button _cancelButton;

protected InitTask _initTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    _percentField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percent_field);
    _cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
    _cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new CancelButtonListener());
    _initTask = new InitTask();
    _initTask.execute(this);
}

protected class CancelButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        _initTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

/**
 * sub-class of AsyncTask
 */
protected class InitTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Integer, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {

        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 50) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                publishProgress(i);
                i++;
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("makemachine", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return "COMPLETE!";
    }

    // -- gets called just before thread begins
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.i("makemachine", "onPreExecute()");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        Log.i("makemachine", "onProgressUpdate(): " + String.valueOf(values[0]));
        _percentField.setText((values[0] * 2) + "%");
        _percentField.setTextSize(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        customCancelMethod("Cancelled");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled(String values) {
        customCancelMethod(values);

    }
    protected void customCancelMethod(String val) {
        Log.i("makemachine", "onCancelled()"+val);
        _percentField.setText("Cancelled!");
        _percentField.setTextColor(0xFFFF0000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            customCancelMethod(result);
        } else {

            Log.i("makemachine", "onPostExecute(): " + result+" "+isCancelled());
            _percentField.setText(result);
            _percentField.setTextColor(0xFF69adea);
            _cancelButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Log when i press the cancel button at 36%:

```
06-26 03:46:01.281 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onPreExecute()
06-26 03:46:01.358 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 0
06-26 03:46:01.385 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 1
06-26 03:46:01.436 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 2
06-26 03:46:01.487 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 3
06-26 03:46:01.539 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 4
06-26 03:46:01.589 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 5
06-26 03:46:01.640 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 6
06-26 03:46:01.691 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 7
06-26 03:46:01.741 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 8
06-26 03:46:01.792 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 9
06-26 03:46:01.843 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 10
06-26 03:46:01.894 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 11
06-26 03:46:01.944 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 12
06-26 03:46:01.995 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 13
06-26 03:46:02.045 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 14
06-26 03:46:02.096 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 15
06-26 03:46:02.146 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 16
06-26 03:46:02.197 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 17
06-26 03:46:02.248 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 18
```

Log when I don't press the cancel button and let the task complete:

```
06-26 03:51:01.983 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onPreExecute()
06-26 03:51:02.073 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 0
06-26 03:51:02.096 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 1
06-26 03:51:02.147 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 2
06-26 03:51:02.199 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 3
06-26 03:51:02.250 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 4
06-26 03:51:02.301 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 5
06-26 03:51:02.351 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 6
06-26 03:51:02.402 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 7
06-26 03:51:02.453 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 8
06-26 03:51:02.504 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 9
06-26 03:51:02.554 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 10
06-26 03:51:02.605 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 11
06-26 03:51:02.656 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 12
06-26 03:51:02.708 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 13
06-26 03:51:02.759 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 14
06-26 03:51:02.811 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 15
06-26 03:51:02.861 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 16
06-26 03:51:02.912 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 17
06-26 03:51:02.964 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 18
06-26 03:51:03.015 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 19
06-26 03:51:03.066 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 20
06-26 03:51:03.116 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 21
06-26 03:51:03.167 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 22
06-26 03:51:03.218 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 23
06-26 03:51:03.268 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 24
06-26 03:51:03.319 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 25
06-26 03:51:03.370 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 26
06-26 03:51:03.420 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 27
06-26 03:51:03.471 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 28
06-26 03:51:03.522 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 29
06-26 03:51:03.573 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 30
06-26 03:51:03.624 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 31
06-26 03:51:03.674 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 32
06-26 03:51:03.725 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 33
06-26 03:51:03.775 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 34
06-26 03:51:03.826 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 35
06-26 03:51:03.877 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 36
06-26 03:51:03.928 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 37
06-26 03:51:03.979 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 38
06-26 03:51:04.030 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 39
06-26 03:51:04.080 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 40
06-26 03:51:04.131 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 41
06-26 03:51:04.182 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 42
06-26 03:51:04.233 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 43
06-26 03:51:04.283 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 44
06-26 03:51:04.334 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 45
06-26 03:51:04.385 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 46
06-26 03:51:04.436 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 47
06-26 03:51:04.486 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 48
06-26 03:51:04.537 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 49
06-26 03:51:04.588 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onProgressUpdate(): 50
06-26 03:51:04.598 14889-14889/com.practise.himanshu.loader I/makemachine: onPostExecute(): COMPLETE! false
```

**EDIT:** *Changed the MainActivity.java to use OnCancelled(Return return) still onCancelled not being called.*

Comment: try overriding `protected void onCancelled(Result result)` instead of `protected void onCancelled()`

Comment: @Onur tried it, the  `onCancelled(String result)` is still not being called. And if it should work when and where are we passing the arguments to `onCancelled()`; i remember passing a boolean.I do not understand this part.